# Node.js Close Current Google Chrome Tab

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to make a twitch notifier when a streamer goes live on twitch. I am able to make a chrome tab using the open npm but I am unable to close it when the streamer goes offline. I am out of ideas on how to approach this issue, the only idea I have is to make an AutoHotkey file making it Ctrl + W.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.close():`

```
close();
```

Example through a function:

```
function closeCurrentWindow() {
    close();
}
```

Comment: This did nothing?